# Outlook Redemption throws MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED error saving RDOMail using unwrapped RDOStore

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

This is a follow up question from [Outlook interop code throws "message has been changed" error the second time when the code tries to save a mail item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460902).

While the unwrapped store works fine for quite some time, today I found a client machine using IMAP account that even the unwrapped store is throwing the MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED error when calling the `RDOMail.Save` method.

Here is the sample C# code:

```cs
var rdoSession= RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = new Application().Session.MAPIOBJECT;
var rdoMail = rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem);
var unwrappedRdoStore = rdoSession.Stores.UnwrapStore(rdoMail.Parent.Store);
var unwrappedRdoMail = unwrappedRdoStore.GetMessageFromID(mailItem.entryId);
unwrappedRdoMail.Subject = "new subject";
unwrappedRdoMail.Save();
```

The `Save` call throws the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040109): Error in IMAPIProp::SaveChanges: MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED
ulVersion: 0
Component: Outlook Data File
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 805634562
```

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Where does mailItem object come from? Has it already been saved?

Comment: The `mailItem` was obtained from `Inspector.CurrentItem` when an email is opened in it's own Outlook window. My code attempts to save the item the normal way, and if a `COMException` is raised with the message "The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed." the code will attempt to unwrap the store and save it again: `try { mailItem.Save(); } catch (COMException e) { if (e.Message == itemChangedMessage) { /* unwrap and save again here */ } }`.

Comment: But if you are only setting the Subject property, Outlook UI won't see your change anyway. Why not set the Subject property through OOM?

Comment: Changing the subject was just my sample code, the actual code is updating MAPI properties for the mail item: `try { mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(schemaName, propertyValue);  mailItem.Save(); } catch (COMException e) { if (e.Message == itemChangedMessage) { /* unwrap */ unwrappedRdoMail.Fields[schemaName] = propertyValue; unwrappedRdoMail.Save(); }`.

Comment: You can try to force your changes by using RDOMai..SaveAs("", 4). If no file name is specified in a call to SaveAS, Redemption performs Save with the flags specified as the second parameter (4 = FORCE_SAVE).